# Recursive function:What is the difference between C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++, recursion

Here is the `Binary Search` code in Python:

```
def binarySearch(arr,key,low,high):
    if high < low:
        return -1
    mid = (low+high) >> 1
    if arr[mid] < key:
        binarySearch(arr,key,mid+1,high)
    elif arr[mid] > key:
        binarySearch(arr,key,low,mid-1)
    else:
        return mid
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
length = len(arr)
result = binarySearch(arr,6,0,length-1)
print('result:',result)
```

Output:

```
result:None
```

But I expected:

```
result:5
```

Then，I write the similar code in C++：

```
int binarySearch(int arr[],int key,int low,int high)
{
    if(high < low)
        return -1;
    int mid = (low+high) >> 1;
    if(arr[mid] < key)
        binarySearch(arr,key,mid+1,high);
    else if(arr[mid] > key)
        binarySearch(arr,key,low,mid-1);
    else
        return mid;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int result = binarySearch(arr,6,0,len-1);
    cout<<"result:"<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result:5
```

It works perfect.
Can anyone explain the reason for this strange behavior?
**P.S.** I know I should use

```
return binarySearch(...)
```

in Python,but I want to know why the C++ code can works perfect.

Comment: This isn't really about the C++ but rather about a bug in your Python. You don't return anything in the `if` or `elif` block. Only the `else` has a `return` statement. Try `return binarySearch(...)` in your `if` and `elif` blocks

Comment: Your C++ code is as buggy as your python code, btw.

Comment: @Arc676 But why the C++ code can works perfect?

Comment: No idea. I'm really more of a C guy than a C++ guy. Maybe in C++ the `return` is implied because you have to return something in C++ but not in Python? Maybe it's a compiler optimization.

Comment: @Arc676, you see an effect of undefined behavior. I assume that program expects to see return value on top of stack and sees "5" left on stack from last recursive call.

Comment: @Arc676 You can write the similar code in C,it can works perfect also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ code **doesn't** work perfectly. It's **undefined behavior** and everything can happen. That includes working, just suddenly stopping to work tomorrow, or on Christmas eve and delete all your files...

C++ standard draft n4527 (`6.6.3/2 [stmt.return]`):

> The expression or braced-init-list of a return statement is called its operand. A return statement with no operand shall be used only in a function whose return type is cv void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4). A return statement with an operand of type void shall be used only in a function whose return type is cv void. A return statement with any other operand shall be used only in a function whose return type is not cv void; the return statement initializes the object or reference to be returned by copy-initialization (8.5) from the operand. [ Note: A return statement can involve the construction and copy or move of a temporary object (12.2). A copy or move operation associated with a return statement may be
>   elided or considered as an rvalue for the purpose of overload resolution in selecting a constructor (12.8). — end note ] [ Example:

```
std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char* p, int x) {
    return {p,x};
}
```

> — end example ] **Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.**

It clearly specifies the undefined behavior at the end.

That it seems to work in your case is just a random accident, don't count on it. Such code should be fixed.

So in the end it all boils down to python returning `none` if you don't explicitly return something and C++ giving undefined behavior if you tell it that you want to return some type but don't actually do.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a return statement in the seconf `if` and `elifs`. THis code works

```
def binarySearch(arr,key,low,high):
    if high < low:
        return -1
    mid = (low+high) >> 1
    if arr[mid] < key:
        return binarySearch(arr,key,mid+1,high)
    elif arr[mid] > key:
        return binarySearch(arr,key,low,mid-1)
    else:
        return mid
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
length = len(arr)
result = binarySearch(arr,6,0,length-1)
print result # 5
```